# Measuring space complexity?

Tags: computational-complexity

I like using `GeneralUtilities` function `BenchmarkPlot` for estimating time complexities, is there something similar for visualizing space complexity?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by "space complexity"?

Comment: I don't know of any such. I generally double size 2-3 times, checking `MemoryInUse/MaxMemoryUsed` and/or `LeafCount` depending on whether it is intermediate usage or size of result that I'm more interested in.

Comment: @MarcoB space complexity is just memory used for evaluation.

Comment: @MarcoB I guess it should be how the size of memory used scales with the size of the input.